# Make Flask restart only when a specific file is edited

Tags: python-3.x, flask, werkzeug

I have a website set up with Flask (Following the [flask mega tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world)).
I have my `views.py` which I edit as I develop. In the same directory I have a `temp.py` which is edited programmatically.

Right now I have my server set to DEBUG so that every time I edit `views.py`, the server restarts. My problem is, every time my program edits `temp.py`, the server also restarts and this is causing a lot of things to break. 
Is there any way for me to make flask ignore `temp.py` and only look at `views.py` when deciding to restart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Suppress Flask server restarts in debug mode for all source file changes**

Excerpt from [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.Flask.run):

> Flask will suppress any server error with a generic error page unless
>   it is in debug mode. As such to enable just the interactive debugger
>   without the code reloading, you have to invoke `run()` with `debug=True`
>   and `use_reloader=False`.

Following will make sure server will not restart in case if any of the source files are changed:

```
app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=False)
```

**Suppress Flask server restarts in debug mode for some source file changes**

For your particular scenario, where you want to suppress server restart only for some of the source files, I'd use dynamic module loading. The easiest approach to achieve this is to remove particular module from imports and to use [`__import__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function instead.

Example code - call the function `modules.temp.ololo(args)`:

```
try:
    # Dynamic import
    module = __import__('modules.temp')
    try:
        # Execute function
        res = getattr(module, 'ololo')(args)
    except AttributeError:
        flask.current_app.logger.error('Function not found')
except ImportError:
    flask.current_app.logger.error('Module not found')
```

Move your `temp.py` into a module, dedicated for dynamic loading, and adjust your code to use the resources from there in a similar way.

Comment: Thank you but I don't think this does quite what I want? I know how to stop reloading entirely, I was wondering if there is a way to stop reloading for only a particular file. (So changing views.py will cause a reload but changing another file will not)

Comment: Not possible by standard means, but you can use dynamic module loading, which is probably the only way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Updated with dynamic loading example.